# How can I add UnsignedProperties?

Tags: java, xml, sign, xades4j

I'm trying to sign a XML document using XADES-BES and the smart card.
I made some changes in the class SignerBES.java according to my needs and the signature creation is working well !

My question: How can I add UnsignedProperties to get something like this :

```
                <SignerRole>
          <ClaimedRoles>
            <ClaimedRole>EST</ClaimedRole>
          </ClaimedRoles>
        </SignerRole>
      </SignedSignatureProperties>
      <SignedDataObjectProperties>
        <DataObjectFormat ObjectReference="#sigId">
          <Description>des</Description>
          <MimeType>text/xml</MimeType>
          <Encoding>base64</Encoding>
        </DataObjectFormat>
        <CommitmentTypeIndication>
          <CommitmentTypeId>
            <Identifier/>
          </CommitmentTypeId>
          <AllSignedDataObjects/>
          <CommitmentTypeQualifiers>
            <CommitmentTypeQualifier>commitment</CommitmentTypeQualifier>
          </CommitmentTypeQualifiers>
        </CommitmentTypeIndication>
      </SignedDataObjectProperties>
    </SignedProperties>
    <UnsignedProperties>
      <UnsignedSignatureProperties>
        <SignatureTimeStamp>
          <EncapsulatedTimeStamp>noTimStampToken</EncapsulatedTimeStamp>
        </SignatureTimeStamp>
        <CounterSignature/>
        <CompleteCertificateRefs/>
        <CompleteRevocationRefs/>
        <SigAndRefsTimeStamp/>
        <RefsOnlyTimeStamp/>
        <CertificatesValues/>
        <RevocationValues/>
        <ArchiveTimeStamp/>
      </UnsignedSignatureProperties>
    </UnsignedProperties>
  </QualifyingProperties>
</ds:Object>
```

this is a code snippet SignerBES.java:

```
    Collection<SignedSignatureProperty> fsssp = new ArrayList<SignedSignatureProperty>(2);
Collection<UnsignedSignatureProperty> fsusp = new ArrayList<UnsignedSignatureProperty>(2);


getFormatSpecificSignatureProperties(fsssp, fsusp, signingCertificateChain);
// Gather all the signature and data objects properties.
QualifyingProperties qualifProps = qualifPropsProcessor.getQualifyingProperties(
        signedDataObjects, fsssp, fsusp);

// LOG
System.out.println("fsusp"+fsusp.size());
```

I tried to add it at SignerBES.java and DefaultSignaturePropertiesProvider.java but I do not know how I can add it :

```
    public class DefaultSignaturePropertiesProvider implements SignaturePropertiesProvider  
{   
@Override
public void provideProperties(SignaturePropertiesCollector signaturePropsCol)
{
signaturePropsCol.setSigningTime(new SigningTimeProperty());
signaturePropsCol.setSignerRole(new SignerRoleProperty("EST"));

// UnsignedProperty
// OtherUnsignedSignatureProperty otherUnsignedProp=null;    
// signaturePropsCol.addOtherSignatureProperty(otherUnsignedProp);
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I understand completely what you're trying, since it seems you're messing around the lib source code. Anyway, check out [this page on the project docs](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/wiki/DefiningQualifyingProperties#optional-signature-properties).

Many of the unsigned qualifying properties are added automatically by xades4j when you use one of the signing profiles (e.g. if you use [`XAdesCSigningProfile`](http://luisgoncalves.github.io/xades4j/javadocs/1.4.0/reference/xades4j/production/XadesCSigningProfile.html), CompleteCertificateRefs/CompleteRevocationRefs are added).

Other properties are part of advanced forms and can only be added during validation of an existing signature. Refer to [this wiki page](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/wiki/SignatureEnrichment#extending-a-signature) and [this javadocs page](http://luisgoncalves.github.io/xades4j/javadocs/1.4.0/reference/xades4j/verification/XadesVerifier.html#verify(org.w3c.dom.Element, xades4j.verification.SignatureSpecificVerificationOptions, xades4j.production.XadesSignatureFormatExtender, xades4j.verification.XAdESForm)) for additional info.

Finally, some properties (e.g. CounterSignature) are not tied to any specific form, and can be added to any signature using a custom [`SignaturePropertiesProvider`](https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/wiki/DefiningQualifyingProperties#optional-signature-properties), registered on the **signing profile** that you are using.

Comment: Thank you Luis. I am a beginner for signing with SmartCard. It's possible to add something like this: signaturePropsCol.addOtherSignatureProperty (otherUnsignedProp)
Because there are several UnsignedProperties to add and they are advanced (not clear to me)? Does the signature check become invalid if I manually add the <UnsignedProperties> block? .

Comment: As I said on the response, using xades4j you don't add it like a list. Unsigned signature properties for specific forms are added automatically when using the corresponding signing profile. Other unsigned properties can be added via a custom SignaturePropertiesProvider